# Digits in shiny DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

After upgrading to R version 4.3.1 and DT 0.28, in shiny DT tables sometimes have a lot of digits, but in the dataframe the number is rounded to 2 digits.
Is it possible to solve without using DT::formatRound()?

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeMeA.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXLeb.png)

**Edit 1**

When creating a dataframe manually, I get the datatable as I would like to see it (Image 1).

```
dt <- data.table(Sec = c("ALRS", "VKCO"), Price = c(69.65, 619.80))
datatable(dt, rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = "t"))
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDDPc.png)

A lot of digits is reproduced only in the running shiny (Image 2).

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbTv4.png)

DT::formatRound("price", 3) adds zeros to all elements of a column

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThnLh.png)

If I do as.character(price) in dataframe, then everything in the table is as it should be (Image 4).
But there must be a solution with type numeric / double.

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhV5f.png)

**Edit 2**

[image: Image 5]

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Update"),
  DTOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dt_tbl <- eventReactive(
    eventExpr = input$update,
    ignoreNULL = FALSE,
    valueExpr = data.table(price = round(runif(n = 10, min = 0.8, max = 0.85) / 0.01) * 0.01))
  
  output$tbl <- renderDT(isolate(expr = {
    datatable(dt_tbl(),
              class = "cell-border stripe", extensions = "FixedHeader", selection = "none", rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(dom = "t", fixedHeader = TRUE, paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE,
                             columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"))))
  }))
  
  observe(dataTableProxy("tbl") %>% replaceData(dt_tbl(), rownames = FALSE))
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem with rounding - `round(x / 0.01) * 0.01`

This rounding is ok - `round(x * 100) / 100`. But can't use in my dataframe(

Comment: Please don't share code as images - it makes it much harder for others to help. Can you please edit your question to include a reproducible example (with code in the question showing what you have tried)?

Comment: @ ly0ka; I strongly recommend you give a reason why you want to avoid formatRound, otherewise your question seems unmotivated, as it seems you already have a solution for yourself; yet you are unsatisfied with it in some unspecified way, therefore; how can we avoid making a suggestion that you might be similarly unsatisfied with ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.